# Rails way to offer modified attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The case is simple: I have markdown in my database, and want it parsed on output(*).

`@post.body` is mapped to the posts.body column in the database. Simple, default Activerecord ORM. That column stores the markdown text a user inserts.

Now, I see four ways to offer the markdown rendered version to my views:

**First**, in `app/models/post.rb`:

```
# ...
def body
   markdown = RDiscount.new(body)
   markdown.to_html
end
```

Allowing me to simply call @post.body and get an already rendered version. I do see lots of potential problems with that, e.g. on edit the textfield being pre-filled with the rendered HMTL instead of the markdown code.

**Second** option would be a new attribute in the form of a method

In `app/models/post.rb`:

```
# ...
def body_mardownified
   markdown = RDiscount.new(body)
   markdown.to_html
end
```

Seems cleanest to me.

Or, **third** in a helper in `app/helpers/application_helper.rb`

```
def markdownify(string)
   markdown = RDiscount.new(string)
   markdown.to_html
end
```

Which is used in the view, instead of `<%= body %>`,  `<%= mardownify(body) %>`.

The **fourth** way, would be to parse this in the `PostsController`.

```
def index
  @posts = Post.find(:all)
  @posts.each do |p|
    p.body = RDiscount.new(string).to_html
    @rendered_posts << p
  end
end
```

I am not too familiar with Rails 3 proper method and attribute architecture. How should I go with this? Is there a fifth option? Should I be aware of gotchas, pitfalls or performance issues with one or another of these options?

(*) In future, potentially updated with a database caching layer, or even special columns for rendered versions. But that is beyond the point, merely pointing out, so to avoid discussion on filter-on-output versus filter-on-input :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yet another way would be extending the `String` class with a `to_markdown` method. This has the benefit of working on any string anywhere in your application

```
class String
  def to_markdown
    RDiscount.new(self)
  end
end

@post.body.to_markdown
```

> normal **bold** *italic*

Comment: Sounds like a great and very Ruby-ish way to do this.

Comment: In addition, here are some suggestions on where to place this code: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/266819/where-is-the-best-place-to-add-methods-to-the-integer-class-in-rails

Answer (score 2):

The first option you've described won't work as-is. It will cause an infinite loop because when you call `RDiscount.new(body)` it will use the `body` method you've just defined to pass into RDiscount (which in turn will call itself again, and again, and so on). If you want to do it this way, you'd need to use `RDiscount.new(read_attribute('body'))` instead.

Apart from this fact, I think the first option would be confusing for someone new looking at your app as it would not be instantly clear when they see in your view `@post.body` that this is in fact a modified version of the body.

Personally, I'd go for the second or third options. If you're going to provide it from the model, having a method which describes what it's doing to the body will make it very obvious to anyone else what is going on. If the html version of body will only ever be used in views or mailers (which would be logical), I'd argue that it makes more sense to have the logic in a helper as it seems like the more logical place to have a method that outputs html.

Do not put it in the controller as in your fourth idea, it's really not the right place for it.

Answer (score 1):

If you were using [HAML](http://haml-lang.com/), for example in `app/views/posts/show.html.haml`

```
:markdown
  = @post.body
```

- http://haml-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.HAML_REFERENCE.html#markdown-filter

Comment: I had "introduce-- and migrate to HAML" on my TODOlist. So this is valuable for when that moment arrives :).

Answer (score 0):

How about a reader for `body` that accepts a `parse_with` parameter?

```
def body(parse_with=nil)
  b = read_attribute('body')
  case parse_with
    when :markdown then RDiscount.new(b)
    when :escape then CGI.escape(b)
    else b
  end
end
```

This way, a regular call to `body` will function as it used to, and you can pass a parameter to specify what to render with:

```
@post.body
```

> `normal **bold** *italic*`

```
@post.body(:markdown)
```

> normal **bold** *italic*